# How to capture lambda @edge requests to kinesis?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Is it possible to capture lambda @edge requests, after transformation, to a service like kinesis.

I was thinking I could maybe write to cloudwatch logs as json, and then somehow automatically write every entry to kinesis somehow, maybe through lambda.

Is this possible? This would be used for traffic logs and identity matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write to kinesis directly from a lambda@edge function if you like. Though this would happen synchronously with the execution of the function and, thus, would delay the processing of a request/response by CloudFront.

The use case you are describing would fit nicely in some sort of a tear-down event that can be triggered asynchronously after the request has been fully processed by CloudFront. CloudFront currently does not support such kind of a trigger.

Another option available today is to configure CloudFront access logs delivery to your s3 bucket and parse them as they are delivered. The access logs are delivered to your bucket with up to 24h delay though.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the [synchronous](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/operatorguide/invocation-modes.html) nature of Lambda@Edge and also the performance penalty, I would recommend checking the following:

1. [CloudFront real-time logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/real-time-logs.html), you can get information about requests made to distribution in real-time (logs are delivered within seconds of receiving the requests). You can then use it as a Kinesis endpoint and due further analytics.
2. Refactor your Lambda@Edge to a [Cloudfront Function](https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/aws-cloudfront-functions/), which provides a lower latency since they are executed at the edge location closest to the end user instead of AWS Regions.